# How to use union types with interfaces in graphql

Tags: graphql

Lets say I have a union type and an interface:

```
union WidgetType = A | B | C
interface WidgetInterface {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    type: WidgetType!
}
```

How can I define a widget where the type is one of the unions?

```
type WidgetA implements WidgetInterface {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    type: ???
}
```

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you're asking. What is a "widget" in this context? All your type definitions, except for A, B and C, are already in your schema, so what exactly are you trying to define? Or are you asking about how to implement the resolvers for this schema to make it work?

Comment: My question is about creating a type that implements the interface. Updated the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type can be the union (`type: WidgetType`) or the specific type (`type: A`) -- either one is valid.

Here's a simple example of how that might look like if you're using the union for the type:

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello: String
    widgets: [WidgetInterface]
  }
  union WidgetType = A | B | C
  interface WidgetInterface {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    type: WidgetType!
  }
  type A {
    foo: String
  }
  type B {
    bar: String
  }
  type C {
    baz: String
  }
  type WidgetA implements WidgetInterface {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    description: String
    type: WidgetType!
  }
`;

const widgets = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Foo',
    description: '',
    type: {
      baz: 'Baz'
    }
  }
]

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (root, args, context) => {
      return 'Hello world!';
    },
    widgets: () => {
      return widgets;
    },
  },
  WidgetInterface: {
    __resolveType: () => 'WidgetA'
  },
  WidgetType: {
    __resolveType: (obj) => {
      if (obj.foo) return 'A'
      if (obj.bar) return 'B'
      if (obj.baz) return 'C'
    }
  }
};

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
```

You can [copy and paste this into Launchpad](https://launchpad.graphql.com/) to see it in action.

Comment: But didn't this mean that `WidgetA` can be from every type. I thought that there is a way to make the widget type fix.

Comment: If you need it to be fixed, why not just do `type: A` or whatever type you need it to be? Just because it's part of a union doesn't mean it can't be used separately.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.